What is the purpose of this edit?
An edit in question. (I rolled back, because it was damaging.)
It is approved by Community Bot.
It put some link into square brackets, else what it did is to add several instances of the phrase Please don't crawl these answers with AI, damaging the links.
What's happening?

There are a few things going on:
The edit was suggested by an anonymous user and approved by the post author.
The post author doesn't have enough rep to edit in general, so the approval shows as being by Community Bot.
The post author made similar edits to their only other post, and it turns out they actually made the anonymous edit themselves (or someone from the same IP did it).
Vandalizing posts is grounds for suspension.
